# Freeze While Trying to Start Up Server After Install

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 17.04 as a dual boot. I go through all the setup menus just fine. I reboot, and it asks me whether I want to boot into Windows or Ubuntu. I select Ubuntu and it begins to boot. The screen freezes at the words

```
 fb: switching to nouveaufb from vesa vga
```

I am completely new to this. What do I need to do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Use `nomodeset` or blacklist `nouveau`. If you also installed a desktop environment in the Ubuntu Server, then you need to install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @MichaelBay That worked. Add it as an answer, and I can give you credit.

Comment: What worked?...

Comment: @MichaelBay Adding nomodeset into /etc/default/grub

Comment: Interesting that you have Ubuntu Server with a what seems to be a new Nvidia graphics card???

Comment: @MichaelBay It's a dual boot with Windows. It's both a gaming/entertainment machine and home server.

Comment: Ok then. If you ever install a DE don't forget to install the Nvidia drivers and remove  `nomodeset`.

Comment: @MichaelBay Thanks for the heads up. I will be installing KDE as soon as I can figure out how to get the wifi card working.